# Как себя ведет рекурсия в R, и стоит ли ей пользоваться?

Tags: рекурсия, r

Стоит ли пользоваться в R рекурсией, и ведет ли она себя лучше чем циклы?
Нагружает ли она память? Если рекурсия в R плохой вариант, какая есть альтернатива?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В R рекурсия ведет себя... обычно. Как в LISP/Scheme, подробнее см. [SICP](http://newstar.rinet.ru/~goga/sicp/sicp.pdf).
Пользоваться можно. Но хвостовой рекурсии нет ([объяснение причин](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2011-April/060599.html)), и создать очередь запросов, заняв всю доступную память, тоже нельзя. А вот в языке Julia глубина рекурсии ограничена только объемом памяти (это про альтернативы).

Comment: Зато её можно использовать в Rcpp (в C API надо контролировать сборщик мусора).

Comment: @ArtemKlevtsov В смысле, хвостовую рекурсию?

Comment: А почему нет. Главное, чтобы `Rcpp::wrap` явно или неявно не попал в саму рекурсию. Код внутри - это чистый C/C++ - он только на выходе оборачивается в `Rcpp::wrap`.